# Seeking Recommendations for Implementing Real-Time Indoor Navigation with User Movement Representation on 2D Map in Android App

Tags: android, navigation, motion

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently in the planning phase of developing an indoor navigation Android app, and I'm seeking recommendations on how to implement a specific feature. The primary functionality of the app involves displaying a 2D map where a user's location is represented by a dot. As the user takes steps in real life, I want the dot on the map to move forward and accurately reflect the user's progress toward the destination.

To achieve this, I'm looking for suggestions on the best approach, libraries, or methodologies that can be employed to seamlessly integrate real-time user movement representation on a 2D map. Specifically, I would like insights on:

Tracking User Movement: What are the recommended methods or libraries for accurately tracking a user's movement indoors? Are there any specific sensors or technologies that work well for this purpose?

Real-Time Updating of Map: How can I ensure that the user's movement on the map updates in real-time as they take steps? Are there any performance considerations or optimizations I should be aware of?

Integration with 2D Mapping: Are there any existing libraries or frameworks that facilitate the integration of real-time user movement data with a 2D map? What are the best practices for ensuring smooth and accurate representation?

I appreciate any guidance, experiences, or recommendations the community can provide in helping me tackle this exciting but challenging aspect of my indoor navigation app. Thank you in advance for your insights!

i have tried previously implementing this in 3d unity ARcore and faced a issue that the path line doesn't stay static w.r.t environment and it keeps moving with user which makes the navigation not proper